# I'd like to know if this is a grammatically correct sentence

Tags: what

> It is what to unify and harmony with Nature.

Also, do these two sentences have different meanings:

> A. The aesthetics of nature is what unifies and harmonizes with nature.
>   B. The aesthetics of nature is unity and harmony with nature.

Comment: No, it's not a grammatically correct sentence. Also it's not clear what it's supposed to mean.

Comment: If you added a question mark it would be a grammatically correct sentence, although an unusual word order. "What is it (It is what) to unify and harmony (better "harmonize") with nature?" Answer: "It is tranquility."

Comment: The edit of your question invalidated the two existing answers (even if one was updated to compensate). I have reinstated your original question so that the existing answers will not be seen as off topic. You can rephrase your question further, but please keep the original information intact in some way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Most likely,** the sentence is a mistake, and pretty much gibberish as it stands.

Having said that, under certain special circumstances, it **could** be an acceptable sentence. What we must do is interpret that sentence as having the following structure:

*It is A and B*,

where

*A = what to unify*
          and
*B=harmony with Nature*

are noun phrases (NPs). *A* is a special type of NP called a **fused relative** ([CGEL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521431468), p. 1077). An example of such an NP appears in this sentence: *They seem pleased with **what I gave them**.* Here *what I gave them* is a fused relative NP.

Most likely, there should be a certain *thing* such that this is the thing which we need to 'unify', and also this thing represents 'harmony with Nature'. It would follow that *it*, i.e. this thing, is both 'what to unify' (i.e. what we have to unify') as well as 'harmony with Nature'.

I've spent a couple of minutes trying to dream up such a *thing*. So far no luck, but I'd be surprized if such a thing absolutely could not be imagined (probably an appropriate back-story will need to be provided as well).

So, the sentence is almost certainly a mistake of some sort. But, arguably, there **are** circumstances, strange and unlikely as they may be, under which the sentence is acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

**Response to edited question -**

First: if you are using "aesthetics" to mean the idea / study of aesthetics, then it is singular (as you have it).  However, that form does not tend to have "the" in front of it - just "aesthetics of nature."  When you are saying "the aesthetics of nature," you are not referring to the study / idea of aesthetics, but rather to the aesthetic qualities nature possesses.  In that case you do need a "the" - but the term is then plural, and "the aesthetics of nature is" changes to "the aesthetics of nature are."

That said,
Sentence A does not make a lot of sense.  (The) aesthetics of nature stem(s) from nature. It does not make sense to say that it/they harmonize(s) or unify(ies) with nature, since they were never separate.

Sentence B does not make a lot of sense either, for a similar reason.  If said aesthetics stem(s) from nature, it (they) cannot be unity and harmony with it. Rather, it is rather an aspect of it, or a result of it. It's a bit like saying "the shape of this sculpture is what unifies and harmonizes with this sculpture." The two cannot be linked through harmony because they are linked by definition.

**Response to original question -**

No.

Unify is a verb, and harmony is a noun. They cannot be linked by "and," in the same way thatFirst: if you cannot say "A lion hunts and predator."

Additionally, the beginning ofare using "aesthetics" to mean the sentence - it is what to unifyidea - is nearly nonsensical. Are you saying "It/ study of aesthetics, then it is the thing that unifies?" Or aresingular (as you saying "It is whathave it means to unify?" Does "it" refer to a specific object, an action). However, or an earlier sentence?

Based on your clarificationthat form does not tend to have "the" in front of it - "The aestheticjust "aesthetics of nature is what to unify harmony with nature" - I am guessing that what." When you mean to say is *Theare saying "the aesthetics of nature is what unifies harmony with nature.,"

The correct form you are not referring to use here is the third person singular "unifiesstudy / idea of aesthetics," as it actively relates but rather to what the aesthetic is doingqualities nature possesses. In that case you do need a "the" (more on- but the word "aesthetic" later). Alternativelyterm is then plural, you can say "Theand "the aesthetics of nature is what servesis" changes to unify harmony with"the aesthetics of nature," in which case the infinitive form is appropriate are."

The sentence then becomes grammatically correctThat said, but still needs some work Sentence A does not make a lot of sense. For instance, I would try to replace one (The) aesthetics of the "natures" with a synonym to make the phrasing less awkwardnature stem(s) from nature. It feelsIt does not make sense to mesay that, if something serves to unify two things, it should probably not be an innate part of one of them. Perhaps you could even remove one of them entirely: "Aesthetics is what unifies harmony/they harmonize(s) or unify(ies) with nature, since they were never separate."

Note - if you are talking about aesthetics as a general idea, use the singular "unifies,"Sentence B does not plural. If, however, you are talking aboutmake a specific setlot of aesthetic qualitiessense either, you can keep "unify" pluralfor a similar reason. And, in either case If said aesthetics stem(s) from nature, change "aesthetic" to "aestheticsit (they) cannot be unity and harmony with it." "Aesthetics" is Unity and harmony implies the generally accepted nounconnection between two separate things, and can be read as either singular or plural; "aesthetic"neither of which is usuallyan inseparable part of the adjectiveother.